# Python 3 multiple replacements

Tags: python, replace, python-3.4

I don't see why this has been placed on hold as "off topic." I am asking for programming help, not a reference (which is what the explanation of why it was closed said). Here's my original question:
I have a python 3 script to send emails in HTML to a list of about 600 people. Sendmail apparently can't send non-ascii characters above 127 (decimal) unless I jump through hoops with MIME. So I'm considering doing a bulk replace of all accented characters with their HTML &#...; equivalents.

I'd rather not use regex, since I'm not proficient at them. Is there way to do this without using a loop, or at least not a complicated one?

Comment: `str.replace()` replaces *all* replacements in the string; no need for a loop.

Comment: The obvious thing is to use a dictionary of replacements. Given such a dictionary, 1 line of code is enough to do the replacements: `s = ''.join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in s)`

Comment: The problem with str.replace() is that I'd have to have about 30 of them.

Answer (score 2):

Googled "python encode html entities", first result: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml:

> #### Builtin HTML/XML escaping via ASCII encoding
>
> A very easy way to transform non-ASCII characters like German umlauts or letters with accents into their HTML equivalents is simply encoding them from unicode to ASCII and use the xmlcharrefreplace encoding error handling:

```
>>> a = u"äöüßáà"
>>> a.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&#228;&#246;&#252;&#223;&#225;&#224;'
```

Comment: I tried a copy and paste of the two lines above, but got this error:    codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>. Maybe I need to import something?

Comment: Wait, the error was due to my having a line about code pages at the top of the file, left over from earlier experimentation. I do now get the output shown above. I will go with this solution, which is extremely economical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate) and the entities from the [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html) package:

```
import html

text = "a text with ä and ö"
ent = {k: '&{};'.format(v) for k, v in html.entities.codepoint2name.items()}
print(text.translate(ent))
```

Output:

```
a text with &auml; and &ouml;
```